# unable to pass ajax post in java script method

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

i came across with a minor conflict while i am reading the html image value and passing value data in java script method works fine, and in ajax POST to pass the value towards controller, and unforunelty ajax point the controller over break point but the string Country parameter is null (passing a null value =), may i know the reason why please ! Thank you !

```
public ActionResult Prayer_Schedule(string Country){

}


<img src="~/images/flags/india.jpg" value="india" onclick="choose(this);">

<script type="text/javascript">

    function choose(element) {
        var Country = element.getAttribute("value"); 
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../Home/Prayer_Schedule',
            data: {
                Country: Country,
            },
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            timeout: 100000,
            success: function (response) {
                alert('ajax success: ' + response);
                //location.href = "/thankyou.html";
            }
        });
```

Comment: what is the conflict/error you are getting. could u please post it

Comment: var Country = element.getAttribute("value"); 
alert(Country);
what the alert say is there any value or null ?

Comment: well i do get the country name , but i can not POST toward controller using  ajax POST

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [jQuery.param](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) for post

```
 data: jQuery.param({ Country: Country}),
```

Or use $.post

```
$.post('../Home/Prayer_Schedule', { Country: Country },
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution ! now i do get the value in C# method parameter !

Answer (score 0):

You have set `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'` so you need to send `json object` or you can simply remove this to get value in controller.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../Home/Prayer_Schedule',
        data: {
            Country: Country,
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        timeout: 100000,
        success: function (response) {
            alert('ajax success: ' + response);
            //location.href = "/thankyou.html";
        }
    });
```

Also if you have not decorated your `method` with `HttpPost` you will need this too.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Prayer_Schedule(string Country){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be your javascript on the getAttribute() function. You are using value, which isn't a valid attribute for an img tag. Try this instead, using data-* attributes:

```
<img src="~/images/flags/india.jpg" data-value="india" onclick="choose(this);">
```

then in your javascript:

```
element.getAttribute("data-value");
```